# Как в propertie-файле указать диапазон букв?

Tags: java, файлы, properties

Имеется propertie файл в котором содержаться символы:

```
intend=' '
bracketClose='}'
intendSize=4
endOfString='\n'
semicolon=';'
bracketOpen='{'
parenthesisOpen='('
parenthesisClose=')'
plus='+'
aMinus='-'
multiplication='*'
division='/'
more='>'
less='<'
equally='='
```

Также туда нужно внести буквы латинского алфавита. Естественно что все 26 букв записывать не вариант, так как обрабатываться всё будет в одном методе.
Вроде такого:

```
public char isLetter() { return letters;}
```

Есть ли возможность использовать другие методы, без регулярных выражений?

Comment: Давайте уточним Вы используете файл propertie для хранения  эталонных  символов? и среди прочего Вам необходимо добавить в данный файл и все буквенные символы(или подсказать способ хранения)? Поясните тогда работу вашего метода *public char isLetter() { return letters;}* судя по типу возвращаемого значения - вернется 1 char , Судя по имени он проверят является ли нечто Буквой , а имя возвращаемой переменной скорее относиться к массиву...

Comment: Я работаю над форматером кода. Стараюсь следовать SOLID принципам, и избавиться от оператора switch при помощи полиморфизма. Камнем преткновения служит запись букв так как это проверки. Мне не обязательно записывать буквы именно в propertie(если это невозможно). isLetter должен возвращать абстрактную букву. То есть не должно быть заранее известно что это за буква, и она ли это вообще. – Abraham прямо сейчас   править

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте надеюсь я правильно понял Ваш вопрос:
Касательно способов хранения вы можете позволить хранить диапазон ASCII кодировки (65-90/97-122) и проводить сортировку по этому признаку.
Пример:

```
"exa*>m/12ple33 of a chara9448cter st2332ring".chars().parallel().filter((s) -> {
            return 65 <= s & s <= 95 || 97 <= s & s <= 122;
        }).sequential().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Как еще один вариант развития событий Вы можете использовать статические методы класса Character к примеру isLetter(char ch).
Пример:

```
"exa*>m/le33 ofacha cterst2332ring".chars().parallel().filter(Character::isLetter)
                    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

(В классе [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) присутствуют много полезных методов как то isNumber etc)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло